# Segmentation fault. Use of vectors cpp

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

When I submit the below code in SPOJ, it is giving a runtime error. Though it is working fine on my compiler. May be due to test cases or something. I am new to comp programming. Please help me figure out the mistake.
The problem is:
http://www.spoj.com/problems/ANARC05B/en/
The input is in sorted order always.
Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    int element;
    vector<int> v1(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      scanf("%d",&element);
      v1[i]=element;
    }
    int m;
    scanf("%d",&m);
    vector<int> v2(m);
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&element);
        v2[i]=element;
    }
    vector<int> v3; //vector of common elements
    int j=0;
    if(m>n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
           if(binary_search(v2.begin(),v2.end(),v1[i]))
           {
               v3.push_back(v1[i]);
           }
        }
    }
    else if(n>=m)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
           if(binary_search(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2[i]))
           {
               v3.push_back(v2[i]);
           }
        }
    }
    vector<int> v4;  //vector of sum of parts upto common elements in v1
    j=0;
    int k;
    int sum;
    for(int i=0;i<v3.size()+1;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(k=j;k<v1.size();k++)
        {
           sum=sum+v1[k];
           if(v1[k]==v3[i])
                break;
        }
        j=k+1;
        v4.push_back(sum);
    }
    vector<int> v5;  //vector of sum of parts upto common elements in v2
    j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<v3.size()+1;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(k=j;k<v2.size();k++)
        {
           sum=sum+v2[k];
           if(v2[k]==v3[i])
                break;
        }
        j=k+1;
        v5.push_back(sum);
    }
    sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<v4.size();i++)
    {
        if(v4[i]>v5[i])
            sum=sum+v4[i];
        else
            sum=sum+v5[i];
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);if(n==0) return 0;` What do you have in mind for cases where the user wants to input zero?

Comment: `binary_search` is not going to work well on unsorted data. Also take a look into using [std::set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: I'm out of close votes, but the following certainly applies: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). "_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you ran out of close votes!? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: It is given in the question. If first element of input is 0. Stop. You may check the problem

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, it was a boring day today, and I've spent too much time on tidying the c++ queue :-( ...

Comment: @facebook-100003312828525 Asking for SPOJ behaviours is bad from the bones here, because no one knows about their engines inner workings. Though you might reassemble the failing testcase at your local build environment first, and debug what's going wrong actually. Please don't ask such questions at SO, we're not your free online debugging service or helpdesk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code but this off-by-one stands out:

```
for(int i=0;i<v3.size()+1;i++)
                      ^^^^
        // ...
        if(v2[k]==v3[i])
                   ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare your vector with a size, then continue to `push_back` to add elements

```
vector<int> v1(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  scanf("%d",&element);
  v1.push_back(element);
}
```

So if `n` was `5`, you would have 10 elements. 5 were initialized, then 5 are pushed back.

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
 ^initialized   ^push_back
```

You should `reserve`

```
vector<int> v1;
v1.reserve(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  scanf("%d",&element);
  v1.push_back(element);
}
```

or declare with the correct size, then use `operator[]`

```
vector<int> v1(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  scanf("%d",&element);
  v1[i] = element;
}
```

Comment: I won't downvote because it is is a legitimate bug in the code, but the question asks about a segfault and I don't think this is the source of it (the other answer provides a plausible explanation for this).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this bug out.

Answer (score 0):

You try to make binary search on non-sorted array which is not supported by function. I am not sure if it can lead to segmentation fault but it is clearly not correct.

Comment: The input is in sorted order always. Edited.